# Polynomials space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $L_1$ and $L_2$ be subspaces of linear space $L$. Let $\dim L_1+\dim L_2=\dim L$. Then there is a linear operator A such that $\ker A=L_1$, $\operatorname{im} A=L_2$. Is that a valid theorem? If not, then disprove the theorem

Comment: Your choice of title and tags is strange, seeing as this post has nothing to do with polynomials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v_1, \dots, v_m$ be a basis for $L_1$. Extend this to a basis $v_1, \dots, v_m, v_{m+1}, \dots, v_n$ for $L$. Let $u_1, \dots, u_k$ be a basis for $L_2$. Since $n = \dim L = \dim L_1 + \dim L_2 = m + k$, we can define a linear map $f : L \to L$ by
$$f(v_i) = \begin{cases} 0 &: 1 \leq i \leq m \\ u_{i-m} &: m < i \leq n\end{cases}$$
It's easily shown that $\ker(f) = L_1$ and $\operatorname{im}(f) = L_2$.